# dplyr: adding qualifying column names while doing scoped filtering ("filter_all", ...)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a very wide & long data set from which I need to pick out rows where any of a selection of variables meet certain conditions.  So far, scoped filtering in `dplyr` along with `any_vars` are very close to what I need.  To illustrate:

```
x <- tibble(v1 = c(1, 1, 5, 3, 4), v2 = c(3, 1, 2, 1, 2))
filter_all(x, any_vars( . == min(.)))
```

produces

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   3
2     1   1
3     3   1
```

I want to add the name of the "filtering variable" to the resulting rows as shown below:

```
     v1    v2   var
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1   3    v1
2     1   1    v1
3     1   1    v2
4     3   1    v2
```

Any suggestions?  I suspect that one of the `map` function in `purrr` may work to do the filtering one by one and then combine the results afterwards.

When one qualify for multiple variables (Thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper),  I'd like show the row multiple times --- both with `v1` and `v2` in this case.

Comment: what should happen if `v1` and `v2` are both min on this row ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  Thanks.  I'd like show the row twice --- first with `v1`, then with `v2`.

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the idea to create new columns, my solution below stores the variable names first prior to the filtering. Let me know if you can improve upon this:

```
x %>%  
  mutate_all(funs(qual = . == min(.))) %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("_qual")), any_vars(. == TRUE)) %>%
  gather(var, qual, ends_with("_qual")) %>%
  filter(qual==TRUE) %>%
  select(-qual) %>%
  extract(var, "var")
```

the intermediate table after the first step:

```
     v1    v2 v1_qual v2_qual
1     1     3    TRUE   FALSE
2     1     1    TRUE    TRUE
3     5     2   FALSE   FALSE
4     3     1   FALSE    TRUE
5     4     2   FALSE   FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

There you go, this should scale for a wide dataset.

```
x <- tibble(v1 = c(1, 1, 5, 3, 4), v2 = c(3, 1, 2, 1, 2))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>%
  mutate_all(rank,ties.method ="min") %>%
  gather(var,val) %>%
  cbind(x,.) %>%
  filter(val ==1) %>%
  select(-val)

#   v1 v2 var
# 1  1  3  v1
# 2  1  1  v1
# 3  1  1  v2
# 4  3  1  v2
```

to avoid building big temp table:

```
gathered <- x %>%
  mutate_all(rank,ties.method ="min") %>%
  gather(var,val)
rows_to_keep <- which(gathered$val == 1)
cbind(x[(rows_to_keep-1) %% nrow(x) + 1,],gathered[rows_to_keep,])
```

This is uglier but I think it's the most efficient I could come up with:

```
log_df       <- mutate_all(x,function(x){x==min(x)}) # identify rows that contain min (no time wasted sorting here)
filter1      <- rowSums(log_df)>0  # to get rid of uninteresting rows
x2           <- x[filter1,]
log_df2      <- log_df[filter1,]
gathered     <- gather(log_df2,var,val) # put in long format
rows_to_keep <- which(gathered$val)
cbind(x2[(rows_to_keep-1) %% nrow(x2) + 1,],gathered[rows_to_keep,]) %>% select(-val)
```

Comment: very nice.  I will need to check it out.  One issue is that I have over 100 variables and the solution need to scale.

Comment: It works but it may not be practical for large data set  --- the intermediate table is twice as wide and hundred times long as the original.

Comment: please try with new versions

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  x%>%filter_all(., any_vars( . == min(.)))%>%
 data.frame(.,var=apply(.,1,function(i) names(.)[i==sapply(x,min)]))
```

If this helps please let us know. Thank you.

This code will fail in one condition: If more than one variable in a row are minimums. for example in the example posted, if there is a row which has both 1's then this code will fail. Thank you

Comment: This is not correct, though the output as the same, you're taking the min between v1 and v2, not the filtering variable

Comment: Remember after filtering, you do have a table that is created from the minimums: so the question is that minimum where did it come from?  There is no other minimum apart from it. Try using a different table and see. Or even try going for maximums instead of the minimums and use which.max and see whether you wont get the correct results. the logics behind it is okay. That's why it is giving the correct solution.

Comment: take a look. at the `filter_all` function, you have clearly specified that the variables to be used in the filter is any between v1 and v2. Simple meaning not one of them but any of the two. Meaning the minimum must come from either v1 or v2. So the question is which one gave you the minimum?

Comment: try to do `x$v1 <- x$v1 * 10`, you'll see you'll have only `v2` on your `var` column. Then see the answer I gave, the `var` column stays the same

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean. Thank you